# select from 2 tables where it has the same value or not depending on the search value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wanted to search a value from 2 tables even it has the same column value or not.

e.g

Table 1

**ID** **Name**

```
1 Jump^Eer
2 Mouse
3 M^3ou^2ses
4 NiceMo^7use
5 ^2Pa^1p^7er
6 MickyMouse
7 JerryMouse
```

Table 2

**ID** **Name**

```
1 Jumper
3 Mouses
4 NiceMouse
5 Paper
```

Searching for value "Mouse"

Result will be

```
2 Mouse
3 Mouses
4 NiceMouse
6 MickyMouse
7 JerryMouse
```

Comment: `UNION` them together and use `WHERE name LIKE '%Mouse%'`

Comment: How about SELECT with TOP 3 only that will result to Mouse, Mouses, NiceMouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, [Name] from Table1 where Lower([Name]) like '%mouse%'
union
select ID, [Name] from Table2 where Lower([Name]) like '%mouse%'
```

Comment: How to add order by?

Comment: @Jefferson the easiest way is to use subquery to count rows. it will look something like this.  Select count(ID) from (select ID, [Name] from Table1 where Lower([Name]) like '%mouse%'
union
select ID, [Name] from Table2 where Lower([Name]) like '%mouse%')